# Software center is not working with proxy

Tags: apt, software-center, proxy

I edited the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` with

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://071.12106en068:password@10.1.1.19:80/";    
Acquire::https::proxy "https://071.12106en068:password@10.1.1.19:80/";
```

same with ftp
where `071.12106en068` is my id. Still I am unable to use the software center and it's keep saying check your INTERNET connection

Answer (score -1):

Instead of editing the conf file, try going to System settings in Ubuntu and select Network. Here you can configure the proxy setup for the entire system (see picture below).

Please remember to delete your lines in the conf file first before you do this.

[image]

Comment: -1: The GUI does not let you set a username and password.

Comment: It does indeed. Just enter the same http line that you entered in the conf file. It contains the username and password.

Comment: Does it do URL-encoding? If not, then why bother with this at all?